# Query on WAS 7 LRSSCHEMA

Tags: sql, websphere, derby

I'm in need to do a query update on the standard Derby DB of a WebSphere 7 installation.
Can't find on console management a way to activate a sort of command to execute my statement.

Can't also figure out how to put down a correct Apache Derby client manually to do that since the info in the administration panel are just the schema and the jdbc name.

Is this IBM application server so difficult to access?

Comment: WebSphere is an application server, like JBoss, Weblogic, or Tomcat. It hosts JEE apps you deploy there. It's not an IDE or UI where you can run queries. Maybe you are confusing it with RAD (the IDE tool from IBM)?

Comment: Yes I'm on RAD but it's not important. I've installed the Job Scheduler Batch on the AppServer. It auto builds a Derby and name it LRSSCHEMA. On this schema basically the was instance saves jobs state. I need to launch a query on that schema.

Comment: RAD includes a "Database Explorer" view. Open it. You can connect to a database using it, and run queries. Use the "cog wheel" to configure your connection.

Comment: This question is specific to the Batch component within WebSphere; the database you're talking about is batch-specific rather than general purpose. Following @TheImpaler's instructions, if it helps to find the matching version of the Derby driver you should find it in ${was_install_root}/derby/lib.